# Wrong Shipping and billing Addresses

Tags: magento-1, model, shipping-address, customer-address, billing-address

I am trying to fetch customer addresses on a custom page using below code.

```
$shipId = 'VALID SHIPPING ADDRESS ID';
$billId = 'VALID BILLING ADDRESS ID';
$addressObject = Mage::getModel('customer/address');
$shipAddress = $addressObject->load($shipId);
$billAddress = $addressObject->load($billId);
```

But I don't know why I am getting only the billing address data in `$shipAddress` and `$billAddress`. 
Actually I am getting the address which is lower in the order. For example if modify the code like below

```
$billAddress = $addressObject->load($billId);
$shipAddress = $addressObject->load($shipId);
```

Now I am getting the shipping address in both the variables. 
Please let me know what is the issue here and how this can be fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a misconception in how Magento models work.

They are **not** "loaders" which just give you back a data object.

They represent the entity itself and load **themselves** (this is called "Active Record").

So you have a model `$addressObject` and load it twice, from different ids. The second load overwrites the data from the first load.

Your code only works because `load()` happens to return `$this` for convenience. In the end `$billAddress`, `$shipAddress` and `$addressObject` all hold the **identical object**. Objects in PHP are not copied when you assign them to a different variable, the variable only holds a reference to the actual object.

#### Correct code:

```
$billId = 'VALID BILLING ADDRESS ID';
$shipAddress = Mage::getModel('customer/address')->load($shipId);
$billAddress = Mage::getModel('customer/address')->load($billId);
```

Comment: I have already the code you have mentioned, but it is also not working.

Comment: Sorry for the previous comment, you are right and the code is working. I am using the same code.